# Apache2 ERROR: Site mywebsite.nl does not exist

Tags: apache-http-server, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to install a website built using the Python flask framework. For this I'm following [this tutorial](http://blog.garethdwyer.co.za/2013/07/getting-simple-flask-app-running-on.html). I followed all steps successfully, but when trying to disable the default site and enable mywebsite with the following commands, but I get errors on both commands:

```
$ sudo a2dissite default
ERROR: Site default does not exist!
$ sudo a2ensite mywebsite.nl
ERROR: Site mywebsite.nl does not exist!
```

I've got `mywebsite.nl` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1332 Jan  7  2014 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6437 Jan  7  2014 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  335 Jul  7 13:57 mywebsite.nl
```

and the contents of `mywebsite.nl` are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         WSGIDaemonProcess mywebsite
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mywebsite/app.wsgi

     <Directory /var/www/mywebsite>
            WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the contents of `/var/www/mywebsite/app.wsgi` are:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/mywebsite')

import app as application
```

Since I followed the whole tutorial, I'm kinda unsure where to look for the problem.

Does anybody have a tip on where to start debugging? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

From the output of a2ensite and a2dissite below I now understand that `000-default` is the current default website to disable. But I don't understand why mywebsite.nl is not there. Any code I need to display here for you guys to understand this?

```
$ a2ensite
Your choices are: 000-default default-ssl
Which site(s) do you want to enable (wildcards ok)?
^C
$ a2dissite
Your choices are: 000-default
Which site(s) do you want to disable (wildcards ok)?
^C
```

Comment: Post the output of the a2ensite and a2dissite commands (without any sudo and without any arguments)

Comment: @qasdfdsaq - Thanks for that. I added the output for `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` to the question. It clearly doesn't find `mywebsite.nl`.. Any ideas how I can debug that?

Comment: Are you *sure* you put your config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and that it's readable by apache? And are you *sure* apache is actually installed in `/etc/apache2`? Is it an actual AWS VM you are using?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq - I am sure it is an actual AWS VM I'm using (I just signed up and created the VM). I added some more information to the question (source of wsgi file and mywebsite.nl). Does this give you any more info on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your file has to end with `.conf` but in your case ends with .nl. Renaming it to `mysite.nl.conf` should fix it.